# How to insert <details> in one line with a sentence

Tags: html, css

I have few sentences. In end of first sentence (in this line), I want add the spoiler which will be keep other part of story. I am try do it, but when  clicked on the  More.. -  my text jumping to the next line. I need continue text in one line with  More... Please do not tell me about any scripts, I want use HTML + CSS only. Thanks.

```css
details {
  display: inline-block;
}
summary {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
  <details>
    <summary>
      More..
    </summary>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </details>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make all of your copy elements display 'inline', rather than inline-blocks (so they work like spans rather than divs)

2) Hide the summary element 'More..' when the details are opened, by setting its display to none.

Code follows:

```css
blockquote {
  display: inline;
} 
 
details {
  display: inline;
}

summary {
  display: inline;
}

details[open] summary {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
  <details>
    <summary>
      More..
    </summary>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </details>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make all tag {{ **blockquote, details, summary** }} **display->inline** instead of **inline-block;** inline-block works of booking the whole line and take none but only using inline works as a line and you can add anything in that line and make summary details off when you click on it by **display:none;** like **details[open].summery{display:none;}**

this will turn off your ****MORE**** when you click on it.